# How to maintain ordering of message in Kafka active active site

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a business requirement of maintaining messages in active active site, i am planning to use kafka for the same.
The producer puts messages into JMS/MQ, which will be consumed by KAFKA. 
So when a batch message of 1 million messages are placed in MQ/JMS by producer, Is it possible to maintain the sequence of message in geographically distributed active-active kafka cluster?

(assuming we are having one partition and one consumer per topic)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the order of messages per partition of a topic is preserved. Between different topics there are no guarantees. So if your entire batch is sent to the same single-partition topic by one producer, yes the order will be preserved. There are some nuances of the configuration that you should be aware of, for instance the ordering guarantee will not hold if max inflight requests per connection > 1 and retries are enabled. The defaults, however, are safe. For more details look for "max.in.flight.requests.per.connection" in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration

If your setup has redundant producers with failover, then you may want to consider enabling idempotence.